# One PHP class can be found, but the other cannot

Tags: php, slim, slim-4

I am using the Slim 4 framework and trying to get the routing working, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why my `controller file` cannot be found. I'm used to `laravel` taking care of all these things for me, but I wanted to try `slim` for my latest application.

I have been using http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html as my guide and want my routes to be defined like `ControllerHere:FunctionHere`, but for some reason it does not work.

From my `index.php` I include a `routes.php` file, the contents of which is

```
namespace App;

$app->get('/test1', Test1Controller::class.':home');

$app->get('/test2', '\Test2Controller:home');
```

I then have two files: `Test1Controller` and `Test2Controller`, both in the same app folder as my `routes.php` file.

Following the guide in the link my `/test1` route and Test1Controller load perfectly, but I cannot get Test2Controller to work, the code for which is:

```
namespace App;

use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

class Test2Controller {

    protected $container;


    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }


    public function home($request, $response, $args) {
        $response->getBody()->write("Hello world test2!");
        return $response;
    }

}
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong? The error I get is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Callable \\Test2Controller does not exist
```

Comment: I don't know Slim 4, but I'll assume it's because you're not including the `\App` namespace in the second one. Try doing `$app->get('/test2', '\App\Test2Controller:home');`?

Comment: Either, as suggested by previous comment, use `\App\Test2Controller:home` as the route callback, or like what you did with `/test1`, do the same and use `Test2Controller::class.':home'`

Comment: Oh I'm such an idiot!  To use an expression I "can't see the wood for the trees".  Thanks